# Sending message via Notification Center with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Using `OS X 10.9` `Maverick`, I am trying to write an `AppleScript` notification event.

I've successfully sent a title and a subtitle using this code:

```
set emailFrom to "Johnny Appleseed"
set emailTitle to "The Email Subject"
set emailMessage to "Hello, this is a test"

display notification with title emailFrom subtitle emailTitle
```

I am trying to display the emailFrom, emailTitle and emailMessage so it's formatted like this:
[image]

The AppleScript Notification Center documentation only discusses title and subtitle.

I have tried adding `message` to the display notification, but it has not worked.

```
set emailFrom to "Johnny Appleseed"
set emailTitle to "The Email Subject"
set emailMessage to "Hello, this is a test"

display notification with title emailFrom subtitle emailTitle message emailMessage
```

How can I add the "message" part to the notification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
display notification "Notification Text" with title "Title" subtitle "SubTitle"
```

=>

```
set emailFrom to "Johnny Appleseed"
set emailTitle to "The Email Subject"
set emailMessage to "Hello, this is a test"

display notification emailMessage with title emailFrom subtitle emailTitle
```

Comment: Note also this appears to be a new feature in [Mavericks](http://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/01.html).  This does not work for me on OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: As of 10.10 it's possible to do this with JavaScript too. I posted this Q&A showing how: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27414831/102401.