# Send Mac OS X Notification Center message via JavaScript - 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: javascript, macos, notifications, automation, javascript-automation

How can a message be sent to the Mac OS X [Notification Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notification_Center) using the [JavaScript for Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/) functionality that was introduced in 10.10 Yosemite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages can be sent to Notification Center via Automator and Script Editor JavaScripts by using the `includeStandardAdditions` method from the core library. For example:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.displayNotification('Basic message')
```

The Script Editor application has documentation that shows they rest of the options. It can be accessed from the "Window -> Library" Menu and choosing the "StandardAdditions" Library and searching for the "displayNotification" command.

This example uses the full set of options:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

app.displayNotification('Advanced message', { 
  withTitle: 'Message Title',
  subtitle: 'Subtitle', 
  soundName: 'Sosumi'
})
```